# Count up figure starting 00:00:01 01/01/(2015) by 357 every 1 second and separate number into financial figure

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to Increment figure starting 01/01/2015 (year variable) by $357 every 1 second?

I need some help to make this little visualisation work properly, as I have an output but far from what I want!!. Any help gratefully appreciated!

[Idea is for:]
The counter to count UP in ($) dollars. If The date:time and calculate number of seconds from 01/01/2015 00:00:01 and multiply by $357, that will give the amount of direct amount forecast for 2015!

[Therefore:]
At noon today (30/06/2015) amount is is 15,595,199 seconds, multiplied by $357 equals $5,569,555,081 and counting.........

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: Is this some new kind of javascript activism?

Comment: @depperm - I thought the question was clear..... @ m69 - it is for a visualisation with an activism element to it. Perhaps a suggestion of how to phrase it, as I would very much appreciate help with making this little feature work!?!?!

Comment: Not 100% I understand what you're after, but heres a demo that takes tot dates, calculates seconds between those dates and shows dollar figure ( $357.13 per second)...  if you need it to AUTO calculate and advance every second, you should be able to modify it to take timestamps as the dates, then re-run the function using setInterval every 1 second.  This is just offered up to get you started and is based off of a somewhat similar need I had for a project a while back.  good luck.  [http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/w0st5z93/](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/w0st5z93/).

Comment: I guess _multiplication_ is too hard a concept for people to grasp on their own nowadays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, you're friendly! First JS project for me. Used "plugins" before but never tried building my own script till now! Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var startDate;
var endDate;

$(document).ready(function() {
    function UpdateDollars(){
        startDate = new Date('1/1/2015 00:00:01 AM GMT').getTime();
        endDate = new Date().getTime();
        var moneyValue=Math.floor((endDate-startDate)/1000)*549;
        $('#dollar-figure').text('$' + moneyValue.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
    };
    setInterval(function(){
    UpdateDollars();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#dollar-figure {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="dollar-figure"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a javascript solution based on the example mentioned in my comment, that takes a start date 1/1/2015 and and end date (automatically set to the CURRENT date and time, in this demo, not editable by the user) and then it calculates the difference (in days) between the dates (which are first converted to timestamps), then we calculate the number of SECONDS equal to that number of days then multiply by 357.13.

I have it set to update automatically every 2 seconds.

The dollar figure formatting gets a bit weird every now and then but you should be able to figure that out and get it resolved or just round to whole dollar amounts I guess.

Is this what you're after or does it help get you closer to figuring out what you are trying to do?

Good luck.

heres the heart of the demo that does the calculation:

```
    // SHOW THE NUMBER OF DAYS FROM START DATE TO END DATE...
    $('#days-spanned').val(mydiff($('#date-start').val(), $('#date-end').val(), 'days'));
    // SHOW THE NUMBER OF SECONDS FROM START DATE TO END DATE...
    $('#seconds-spanned').val(mydiff($('#date-start').val(), $('#date-end').val(), 'seconds'));
    // MULTIPLY THE NUBMER OF SECONDS BY 357.13 ... AND FORMAT WITH COMMAS AS DOLLAR FIGURE...
    $('#dollar-figure').val('$' + ($('#seconds-spanned').val() * 357.13).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
```

fiddle demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/w0st5z93/]

UPDATE:  to convert the dates to timestamps just do as follows:

```
var startDate = new Date('1/1/2015 7:29:13 PM EDT').getTime(); // would produce 1420154953000
```

Comment: You've definitely got the idea of what I am wanting to achieve, and thank you VERY much for having a look at this! I am very grateful! How would I go about this without using html inputs - dynamically creating an output from year beginning to year end within `<span id="number"></span>` ?

Comment: instead of HTML inputs you would just use variables in javascript.   I used inputs to just visualize it all easily so you could see what was occurring.... actually you could have HTML inputs then just use CSS to HIDE them from view alltogether.   so you can test that in the fiddle and by just adding .hide() for the text fields or any other element you want to NOT show in the DOM.

Comment: I think he's asking how to find out the current number of seconds through the year. Not sure why he doesn't just come out and say so, though..

Comment: @JamesSaint - ok, so if you're inquiring about how to go about finding the number of seconds its simple... instead of human dates convert those to unix timestamps ... so instead of July 5, 2015 at 7:29:13 PM EDT you would have 1436138953... do same for end date and then subtract to get the total number of seconds between those timestamps then multiply times 357.13.

Comment: @JamesSaint and then of course take that resulting figure and do '$("#number").text( RESULT OF CALCULATION HERE );'  to place the answer / dollar figure in that span.

Comment: Thank you @tamak for helping me with this! I feel the end is in sight, but I still can't seem to get it working! Forgive my ignorance, I am very new to javascript (other than using plugins). I have a demo here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wp_saint/gnw7bytr/1/)

Comment: @JamesSaint heres your fiddle corrected and working:  https://jsfiddle.net/tamak/x42ugkf9/.  if this has helped please vote for my answer.

Comment: @tamak Genius! THANK YOU! 99.9% there! How do I now get that figure to dynamically change every second though? As currently only updates on RUN/page refresh? Thanks so much in advance for your help with this!

Comment: @JamesSaint the fiddle is updated now to auto-generate every 1 second.    glad to help.

Comment: @tamak FANTASTIC! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Anything else I can do to bump your reputation up! Thanks for being so patient with me!